# How to achieve `hasOne:withMapping:` in RestKit 0.20?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a JSON data-structure for items of the sort

```
{
    "id": "8a1a39479d03d959", 
    "sortOrder": 3, 
    "timestamp": 1381669499.11, 
}
```

and another file structure that has exactly one item:

```
{
    "id": "d88e3c3d1630db4c", 
    "item": "8a1a39479d03d959", 
    "timestamp": 1381669505.364, 
    "version": 2
}
```

I've been struggling to get this sort of mapping to work, to the point that I added a list of `[files]` to the items JSON just to map the relationship. However, reading an older [post on the Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/X_cKci0USTg), I saw that it supposedly used to be possible to map these relationships like this (not tested code, just paraphrasing the above link):

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *itemMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Item class]];
itemMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"itemID";
[itemMapping mapKeyPath:@"sortOrder" toAttribute:@"sortOrder"];
[itemMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"itemID"];

RKManagedObjectMapping *fileMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[File class]];
fileMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"fileID";
[fileMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"fileID"];
[fileMapping mapKeyPath:@"item" toAttribute:@"itemID"];
[fileMapping mapKeyPath:@"version" toAttribute:@"version"];

[fileMapping hasOne:@"item" withMapping:itemMapping];
[fileMapping connectRelationship:@"organization" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"itemID"];
```

However `hasOne:withMapping:` doesn't exist any more in RestKit 0.20. What is the correct way nowadays to map a one-to-many relationship with an id returned as a simple string in the JSON? Just for reference, I am using CoreData integration in this project.

Comment: Note that the code sample you're referencing is from 0.10.x, not 0.2x, so it won't make much sense... What you're looking for is `foreign key mapping`.

Comment: @Wain Thanks for the edit. I am totally aware that the code sample is from 0.10, that is exactly why I'm asking how to do the same thing in 0.20!

Comment: But you have converted most of the mappings, it's just the relationship you need help with?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was probably a bit unclear. I have a fully functional app that uses 0.20.2 for the mapping, but I've tried and failed for a long time to get a mapping from `File` to `Item`, instead of from `Item` to `File`. Here is my current mapping code: https://gist.github.com/DaGaMs/7105381

Comment: As you can see, I have to send a "files" array in the JSON for `Items` because that was the only way RestKit actually picked up the relationship mapping. I was hoping to get a hint at how to map from a single identifier in the JSON to a CoreData relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your mapping sets the item identity to `identifier`. On the file this corresponds to nothing - it needs to. Add a transient attribute and map the `item` to it (let's call it `itemIdentifier`). Now, you can setup a relationship mapping to fill in the Core Data relationship (which should be bi-directional, I'm assuming `item` <<-> `files`):

```
[fileMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"item" connectedBy:@{ @"itemIdentifier": @"identifier" }];
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much, I didn't realise I had to create a transient attribute to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Item"
                                               inManagedObjectStore:[YourManagedObjectStore];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"sortOrder": @"sortOrder",
                                              @"id":@"itemID"
                                              }];

mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"itemID"];

[mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"organization"
                                         mapping:fileMapping];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying that if I have a one-to-many relationship `Item <----organization---->> File`, I have to add the relationship mapping to the "itemMapping"? My question is rather: how do I set up the "fileMapping" so that it correctly sets the CoreData relationship between Item and File?

Comment: Ok, I just tested this; unfortunately, it doesn't work, i.e. the relationship does not get set, while all other mappings work fine.

Comment: The type of relationship used here is for nested JSON (i.e. direct, not foreign key).